# Dart SDK is not configured in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, dart

I just started learning the Dart programming language, then I did some preparations such as installing the Dart SDK, then setting the path for the bin, after that I checked using the command prompt and it didn't cause any problems. After that I started to code Dart program, and Android Studio gave message "Dart SDK is not configured" , then I clicked "open Dart Setting" and set SDK path, then applied it. But still Android Studio gives message Dart SDK is not configured.

Please help to solve this problem

Answer (score 4):

In the terminal paste the below code after installing dart and flutter

```
$ flutter sdk-path
```

It will show the path of sdk as below.

/home/user-name/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk

Comment: thanx it worked

Answer (score 3):

Under Settings, go to Languages & Frameworks, choose the language you are using and check if the field SDK Path has the correct address. For example, mine is flutter so I have added the correct path as shown in the image. [Dart SDK not configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyS20.png)